# How deal with Redshift lack of support for Arrays

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Redshift does not support Arrays, however my source database has several Array columns that I need in Redshift.

How should this field type be handled when trying to migrate it into Redshift?

Answer (score 18):

While Redshift does not support arrays in the PostgreSQL-sense, it provides some JSON functions you might want to have a look at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html

You can insert arrays into `varchar` columns:

```
create temporary table _test (col1 varchar(20));
insert into _test values ('[1,2,3]');
```

Then using `json_extract_array_element_text()` would yield:

```
db=# select json_extract_array_element_text(col1, 2) from _test;
 json_extract_array_element_text
---------------------------------
 3
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, I could find a way to save collections of values as columns:

```sql
drop table if exists tmp_example;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_example (
    name varchar,
    fruits super ENCODE raw
);

-- you need to use the json parse function to insert data
insert into tmp_example values ( 'Joe',   json_parse('["apple","banana"]'));
insert into tmp_example values ( 'Steve', json_parse('["grapes"]'));
insert into tmp_example values ( 'Dave',  json_parse('[]'));

-- you can query using [index] that will return null if not found
select *, fruits[0] as first_fruit from tmp_example;

--  name  |       fruits       | first_fruit 
-- -------+--------------------+-------------
--  Joe   | ["apple","banana"] | "apple"
--  Steve | ["grapes"]         | "grapes"
--  Dave  | []                 | 
-- (3 rows)

-- you can query the values of the array
-- got any grapes?
select example.name, fruit from tmp_example as example, example.fruits as fruit where fruit = 'grapes';
--  name  |  fruit   
-- -------+----------
--  Steve | "grapes"
-- (1 row)
```

The table can also get the array values from CSV files using the COPY command.

Answer (score -2):

Surround it with a specific character that never appears on this field values.

Example:

```
field = |value1|value2|value3|
```

And when querying it you just do this:

```
where field like '%|value1|%'
```

Also have in mind that `like` queries are expensive and can decrease your cluster's perfomance.