# How to store a set of strings in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to store an array of strings as a table column in Redshift and then check whether this array contains some string.

Since Redshift doesn't support array types, I started looking for ways around it. The only thing I came up is to encode this array as a pipe-separated string, previously escaping all the pipes within the elements of the array. Looking up of the element will be done using regexps.

While this solution seems to be viable, it requires some pre- and post-processing. Maybe you can recommend some alternatives?

Comment: Why not just store the string values in a column in some table?  Is there anything preventing you from doing this?  Pipe or comma separated strings are not normalized data, and are going to be a headache to work with, even in Redshift, which has pretty good regex support.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413299/how-deal-with-redshift-lack-of-support-for-arrays

Comment: @NavjotBhardwaj this doesn't address my problem. I need to look for a specific element in the array, not access it by index.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the data is modeled in a way that prevents storing arrays as a separate table. I mean it is possible but will require much more work than this solution I came up with.

Comment: @OlegTheCat the only possible implementation I can see is using REGEXP_INSTR, please do post what you finally end up using.

Comment: Arrays are a way of de-normalizing your data. The correct approach is to normalize your design and store those strings using a standard one-to-many relationship. Then you can use a simple SQL query and not array functions are required